# C++: Extending static STL container/ map member in subclass?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, stl

Currently I have code that looks a lot like

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

void SomeFunc();
void SomeOtherFunc();

struct Calls {
    std::string name;
    std::function<void(void)> a, b;
};

struct BaseClass
{
    static const std::map<std::string, Calls> callbacks; 
    const std::map<std::string, Calls>* pCallbacks = &callbacks; // Run-time polymorphism, pointers are *typically* upcast back to base class.
};
const std::map<std::string, Calls> BaseClass::callbacks = {{"testX", {"x", SomeFunc, SomeOtherFunc}}};

void MoreFuncs();
void MoreFuncs2();

struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    static const std::map<std::string, Calls> callbacks;
    const std::map<std::string, Calls>* pCallbacks = &callbacks;
};
const std::map<std::string, Calls> DerivedClass::callbacks = {
                {"testX", {"x", SomeFunc, SomeOtherFunc}},
                {"testY", {"g", MoreFuncs, MoreFuncs2}}};

struct DeepClass : DerivedClass
{
    static const std::map<std::string, Calls> callbacks;
    const std::map<std::string, Calls>* pCallbacks = &callbacks;
};
const std::map<std::string, Calls> DeepClass::callbacks = {
                {"testX", {"x", SomeFunc, SomeOtherFunc}},
                {"testY", {"g", MoreFuncs, MoreFuncs2}},
                {"testZ", {"h", SomeOtherFunc, MoreFuncs2}},
};
```

in larger volumes.
Extending this way is tiring, and leaves too much visual cluster in my opinion. Is there any technique to make this easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function like

```
auto concat_maps(std::map<std::string, Calls> first, const std::map<std::string, Calls>& second)
{
    first.insert(second.begin(), second.end());
    return first;
}
```

Which merges one map into another.  This allows you to define your derived class maps as a concatenation of the parent class map and the elements you want to add.  That would look like

```
struct DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    static const std::map<std::string, Calls> callbacks;
    const std::map<std::string, Calls>* pCallbacks = &callbacks;
};
const std::map<std::string, Calls> DerivedClass::callbacks = 
      concat_maps( BaseClass::callbacks, {{"testY", {"g", MoreFuncs, MoreFuncs2}}});

struct DeepClass : DerivedClass
{
    static const std::map<std::string, Calls> callbacks;
    const std::map<std::string, Calls>* pCallbacks = &callbacks;
};
const std::map<std::string, Calls> DeepClass::callbacks = 
      concat_maps( DerivedClass::callbacks, {{"testZ", {"h", SomeOtherFunc, MoreFuncs2}}});
```

Comment: In that case, would there be any way to automatically fill in the first argument / turn this into something I could just copy about?

Comment: @Atherix Are you familiar with macros?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not quite sure how I'd apply that here. There's not a macro or anything to get the base class "of the current class" or anything is there? @NathanOliver

Comment: @atherix there is not, but you could define a type alias in you class called parent that is an alias to the base type.  Then your macro could use that.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that might be my best option actually. Thank you!

Comment: @Atherix You're welcome.  I'll keep thinking about it but that's the best I can up with right now.